# Is loading a big file into memory and keeping it for all the running time of the program wrong?

Tags: c++, memory

## 1. Load file

I have a file of size `330 MB` which I am loading into a multimap as follows:

```
// String = first column and vector<string> rest of the columns
`typedef std::multimap<string, vector<string>> termF`;

ifstream file("file.txt");
  string line = "";
  termF tfidf;
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    while (file.good())
    {
      getline (file, line);
      vector<string> values;
      boost::split(values, line, boost::is_any_of(" "));
      string id = values[0];
      vector<string> vals;
      for(int i = 1; i < values.size(); i++)
      {
        vals.push_back(values[i]);
      }
      tfidf.insert(pair<string,vector<string>>(id, vals));
    }
    file.close();
  }
  return tfidf;
```

---

## 2. Search

I have a list of ids stored in a `vector<string> ids`. I want to check if these ids are in the multimap by using the following code:

```
for(auto &id: ids)
{
  vector<string> values = tfidf.find(id)->second;
}
```

---

## 3. Question

- Instead of loading the file into the memory, is it better to search for the ids directly from the file? it will be like going back and forth between the program and the text file.
- **This file will be kept in memory for all the running of the program**

Comment: `while (file.good())` is generally wrong and can lead to you processing the last line twice.  `while(getline(file, line))` would be a better choice.

Comment: i'll modify it ty @RetiredNinja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is a very subjective question - if you absolutely require maximum (eg in-memory data-base) performance, you don't have memory concerns and you can't change your on-disk data representation, then your options are limited to what you already have.
- If your code is supposed to run under limited memory conditions, such as mobile devices, then you should look up dynamically in the file, and that's where we go to the next option.
- Use a data-base solution and query the db to find your required data. you may implement a caching layer on top of the db or you may use a db that does some caching for you. leveldb is good and simple document-based data-base library. Sqlite is an option too, especially when you need the features of relational db (that depends on the structure of data you store). This option will definitely beat option #2.

Comment: I see it depends on my machine. I think as you mentioned it is better to use a relational db. the File contains more than 800,000 records. Searching through the text file every time is expensive. Option 3 is much better

Comment: Not on your machine per se, but on the types of devices you wish to run the code on. Mobile devies (iphones and such) have much less memory than desktops, server machines and super-computers.

Comment: I loaded the text file into a relational db by using sqlite3. Then I used a query to search for the ID and load the other columns. The program is running smoother. No more ramming.